# CastError: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[]" (type string) at path "comments.undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose-populate

I'm quite new to node and mongoose. I'm trying to do a project using them, but i'm running into an error while trying to populate. The comment is saved to the Comment schema perfectly, but throws an error when i reference it Organization Schema.Please advise me on what i'm doing wrong. Any form of assistance will be appreciated.

```js
// Post route for comment(on the Organization's profile page)
router.post('/comment/:id', ensureAuthenticated,(req, res) =>{
  let id = req.params.id;
  console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id))
  const commentObject = new Comment({
    sender: 'Fred kimani', 
    commentBody: req.body.commentBody
  })
  console.log(commentObject);
  commentObject.save((err, result) =>{
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    else{
      Organization.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$push: {comments: result}}, {upsert: true}, (err, organization) =>{
        if(err){console.log(err)}
        else{
          console.log('======Comments====')
        }
      })
      res.redirect('/users/organizationprofilepage/:id')
    }
  })
});

//Organization Schema

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const OrganizationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  organization_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  isApproved: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  image:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }, 
  comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment'
  }],
  
},
//{ typeKey: '$type' }
);


OrganizationSchema.statics.getOrganizations = async function () {
  try {
    const organizations = await this.find();
    return organizations;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

//defines the layout of the db schema

const Organization = mongoose.model('0rganization', OrganizationSchema);
module.exports = Organization;

//Comment schema

const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const CommentSchema =  mongoose.Schema({

    sender: {
      type: String,
    }, 
    commentBody: { 
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    },
  })


  CommentSchema.statics.getComments= async function () {
    try {
      const comments = await this.find();
      return comments ;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  const Comment= mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
  module.exports = Comment;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to change the `comments` type to `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`:

```
comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Comment',
    },
  ],
```

2. Try to push the new commend `_id` into the `Organization` object after its creation, not the whole object:

```
commentObject.save((err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    Organization.findByIdAndUpdate(
      id,
      { $push: { comments: result._id } }, // <- Change this line
      { upsert: true },
      (err, organization) => { }
    );
    ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just updated the schema you will need to make sure all of the comments are following the new form you created, when you save it will attempt to validate them, that is why an updateOne will work but not await save()